# How to use SharedFrameworks directory inside a macOS loadable bundle

Tags: macos, frameworks, bundle

I'm currently developing native plugins for macOS and so I am packaging my code inside loadable bundles. These .bundles work well, and I am able to manually build, deploy and load the bundle in my applications. Using something besides a loadable bundle is not an option for my purposes.

The problem is that I now have pluginA.bundle with its own internal `Frameworks/` directory that contain a handful of .dylibs, and now I would like to create pluginB.bundle which will use the same .dylibs. How can I do that without having two duplicate `Frameworks/` folder inside the bundle?

I believe the `SharedFrameworks/` folder could be useful, that is, if I could understand what it does... Perhaps I'm missing something but official Apple documentation glosses over it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

For my purposes, I was able to create a pluginA.bundle, a pluginB.bundle, and a pluginCore.bundle. The library paths (i.e. what you see with `otool -L Contents/MacOS/pluginA`) of the executables in A and B go out of their respective bundles and into the `Contents/Frameworks/`of the core bundle.

It works for me, but if anyone would like to still explain the difference be the `Frameworks/` and the `SharedFrameworks/` directory, I'm all ears!

Comment: Will pluginA.bundle always be used with pluginB.Bundle?

Comment: You should be able to use the NSBundle class or CFBundleRef type so that pluginB.bundle would have have access to pluginA.bundle resources.

Comment: My plugins are written in C and so that they can be built and run on multiple platforms (with their corresponding Makefiles to compile them of course). And then the bundles are loaded and managed by Unity (the game development platform) so I don't really have a chance to use NSBundle...

Comment: Actually, now that I consider the constraints that Unity places on how I deploy things, I should have replied "no" to your question... Sorry about that